# How do I determine the exact command line that VS 2010 is using to build a solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msbuild

Generally, we use Visual Studio to build solutions in release mode, and after the build some files get copied to different locations.

Is it posible to know what the exact command line is that is being used by Visual Studio? I want to use that same command line and run it from a batch file, ensuring that my solution gets built the same way that it would inside of Visual Studio.

**Note:** I know how to build solutions from a batch file. Its just that I want to know what my current Visual Studio 2010 configuration is using to build the solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what diagnostic logging actually writes but you can give that a try. The instruction is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj651643.aspx). Or use process explorer to actually get hold of the running msbuild if the logfile doesn't reveal what you need.